# Returning an array from a MySQL query with a JOIN operator

Tags: php, mysql

I have two tables;

**Books**
,book_id
,mbook_id (Relation with mbook_id in the master_books table)
,org_id
,book_rating

**master_books**
,mbook_id
,book_name
,book_authors
,book_summary
,book_pub_date
,book_ISBN10
,book_ISBN13
,book_image

Now the idea is that there are a collection of books in the master_books table, but say there were 3 libraries who all had the same book. Instead of having 3 entries of the book the books table just references the master_books table id for the book information.

To start with i've set up a simple query to get all books, like so;

```
$result = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT books.book_id, master_books.book_name, master_books.book_image FROM books JOIN master_books ON master_books.mbook_id WHERE org_id='" . $org_id . "'");
```

I'm using the following to output the data;

```
$books = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
foreach($books as $x => $x_value) {
    echo "Key=" . $x . ", Value=" . $x_value;
    echo "<br>";
}
```

The result is follows;

```
Key=0, Value=1
Key=book_id, Value=1
Key=1, Value=Picturepedia: 15 Plants (Picturepedia)
Key=book_name, Value=Picturepedia: 15 Plants (Picturepedia)
Key=2, Value=9780751350852.jpg
Key=book_image, Value=9780751350852.jpg
```

I'm trying to figure out why it duplicates with Key=0 and then Key=book_id and so on. The lines beginning with Key=0, Key=1, Key=2 shouldn't be there

Comment: Can you clarify what is the problem?

Comment: Sorry, just changed the last sentence, trying to figure out why i'm getting the key=0, key=1, key=2 lines

Comment: You're using a fetch function which returns a dual-keyed array. THere's nothing unusual about this. It's exactly how mysql/mysqli "fetch" functions have always worked, unless you use one of the single-type return variants. In other words, RTFM: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-array.php

Comment: Thats becuase the mysqli_fetch_array default behaviour is to return both types of data so you get the elements by number and by string key

Comment: Is there a way to avoid that Lupin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you just want to get the array with the key names and not the numeric elements use this instead:

```
$books = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC);
```

Answer (score 0):

It's because [`mysqli_fetch_array`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-array.php) receives 2 parameters and you are ignoring the second: `resulttype`

As of the documentation, you have 3 options:

- `MYSQLI_ASSOC` - you receive the field names on the array key
- `MYSQLI_NUM` - you receive a counter on the array key
- `MYSQLI_BOTH` - you receive both the options, all duplicated. **This is the default.**

As you said that

> The lines beginning with Key=0, Key=1, Key=2 shouldn't be there

I think you want to call it like this: `$books = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC);`

Answer (score 0):

The response is perfectly valid.

The returned array from [`mysqli_fetch_array()`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-array.php) that you store in `$books` represents only one line from your result table.

You can access the columns of your result table either by using the column name, e.g. `book_id`, or by using the position in your `SELECT` statement: `book_id` is the first field you requested, thus index 0, `book_name` is the second, thus index 1 and so forth.

**If you don't want or need the entries with indices, use [`mysqli_fetch_assoc()`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php) instead.**

In order to access the next lines, you have to use a loop:

```
while($books = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {

    // do stuff

}
```

This will fetch another row as long as another row is available. Once you fetched all of them, `mysqli_fetch_array()` will return `NULL`, which evaluates to `false` and the loop will end.